# sort list of dictionaries with sub-dictionaries and random key

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

help for sorting this list

```
from operator import itemgetter
l = [
      {'Ad28b4fac': {'url': 'http://a.com/', 'rating': 0}},
      {'cx28b4ffc': {'url': 'http://www.dbr/', 'rating': 1}}
    ]
# sort this list by rating value
```

I try

```
  sorted(l, key=lambda x : l[x])
```

try

```
l.sort();
```

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda x : list(x.keys())[0])
[{'Ad28b4fac': {'url': 'http://a.com/', 'rating': 0}}, {'cx28b4ffc': {'url': 'http://www.dbr/', 'rating': 1}}]
```

The parameter to the lambda for each iteration is the dictionaries in the list `l`. Now we wish to sort the data on the dictionary key. So the `dict.keys()` function is used which will return all the keys in the dictionary. We take the first one `[0]` which happens to be the only key and sort based on that.

Comment: try this and output is -> 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing

Comment: which python version are you using?

Comment: In python 3 `dict.keys` returns an dict keys object. user `list()` to convert it to list like `list(x.keys())[0]`. See the updated answer.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you

Comment: if you want the highest rating first use: `sorted(l, key=lambda x : list(x.keys())[0], reverse=True)`.

Comment: hiro protagonist, not working, when rating change, order of sites need change also.